# Richtextbox.Document property not defined

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, xaml, richtextbox, rtf

in a vain attempt to display formatted text and links in a windows form, I've tried to use a RichTextBox and insert formatted text into it through `MyRTB.Document;` (I'm using the [RichTextBox Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee681613%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) from MSDN) however, when I tried to use the project, I've found that the Document property is not defined for RichTextBox. I've added the presentationframework.dll assembly and added the `using System.Windows.Controls` as stated on the [property documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.richtextbox.document.aspx) and still no dice. I have no idea why this is happening or how to make it work, any help at all will be appriciated.

Answer (score 6):

The answer will be long overdue,
but perhaps it may help other people who are having the same question.

There are different `RichTextBox` objects that can be created:

one is a `System.Windows.Forms.RichTextBox`. This object is generated when a
`RichTextBox` is dragged into the form using the `toolbox`, this object does not
contain the document property.

another object is from the `System.Windows.Controls.RichTextBox`, this object applies for `WPF(Window Presentation Foundation)`, and thus has the document
property.

I'm a student in electronics, please forgive, and correct any misused terms and such.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
MyRTB.RTF="{\rtf...}";
```